# Word 2010: Add document as appendix to another document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents, page-numbers

I'm working on a large Word document in Word 2010.

I need to include an entire document as an appendix, including title page, it's own table of contents, original line numbering, etc.

The the main document containing the appendix should not "see" the document; it's header numbering should be unaffected, it's page numbering should just skip a the number of pages of the appendix, the TOC should be unchanged, etc.

Is this possible, and how?
If not, what could be a good alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. You need a [master document](http://www.howtogeek.com/73960/create-a-master-document-in-word-2010-from-multiple-documents/). With a master, you can have multiple included documents that can be maintained separately and combined in the master.

To ensure that your appendix documents are totally separate, you should set up a separate set of styles including heading a list styles (if you want numbered appendices). You should also ensure that you reset the page numbering in the footer/header if you don't want the numbers to continue from the main document.

I'm not sure about your comment on the main document "skipping" the numbering of the appendices. The main document should stop before the start of the apendices and then it wont be impacted anyway. As mentioned, the appendices should have their own numbering if you want them or they will continue from the previous page. The master document controls how the sub-documents fit together.